# Xpath sub selector

Tags: xpath

I want to select a node that has a sub node with particular `text() = '...'`.  Any idea how to write this xpath expression?

```
//Node[?]
```

Comment: This is not very specific. If none of my answers help you, then you'll have better luck providing some sample input with desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
//yournode[subnode/text() = 'whatever']
```

?

Answer (score 2):

If the "sub node" is a child element named `subnode`, then use:

```
//Node[subnode='...']
```

Or, if it could be a child element having any name, use:

```
//Node[*='...']
```

If the "sub node" could be nested at an arbitrary depth, then use:

```
//Node[descendant::*='...']
```